# How to make a simple play/pause audio player on a Wix website?

Tags: javascript, html, velo

Right now, I have this code on my website:

```
<audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925"
controls="true" 
volume="1.0">
</audio>
```

Which displays the default audio player like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au2n5.jpg).

But my desired outcome is to only have the play/pause functionality. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2L0T.jpg).

I did some research and found the closest code to my desired outcome [here](https://codepen.io/dmarcus/pen/vKdWxW). I tried to run these code on my Wix website under the **Edit Code** window but nothing seems to work at all.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

I'm a beginner so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.trigger-audio')
let audio = document.querySelector('audio')

button.addEventListener('click',() =>{

  if(button.classList.contains('fa-play')){
     audio.play()
     button.classList.remove('fa-play')
     button.classList.add('fa-pause')
    }else{
     audio.pause();
      button.classList.remove('fa-pause')
     button.classList.add('fa-play')
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
  <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925"
  volume="1.0">
  </audio>
</span>
```

**Solution for multiple buttons [update]**

First of all, we wrap the audio tags inside a container.

```
<div class="container">
        <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
             <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925"
                volume="1.0">
            </audio>
        </span>
         <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
            <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor"
                volume="1.0">
                 </audio>
            </span>
    </div>
```

then we create a simple function that return in an array all of the sibling of a element(using es6 features):

```
function getAllSiblings(el){
            let parent = el.parentElement
            let children = Array.from(parent.children)
            let siblings = children.filter(child => {
                return child !== el
             })
            return siblings
        }
```

then we catch all audio tags and put them in an arraylike object with `let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')`

Now whe loop over this collection and for every element of the collection (aka for every button) we attach on it a click event listener where, once the button is clicked :

we get all his sibling (in our case is only one): `let siblings = getAllSiblings(button)`

then we catch his direct children: `let audio = button.children[0]`, for every button there is only one children so we can use this method, the direct children is the audio tag we want play

Now we check if the the button itself has the class `fa-play`, if it does means that the button is not playng yet, so we play it, we remove the `fa-play` class and replace it with the `fa-pause` class, we also disable all his siblings. So they don't will be played if the current button is playing.

On the contrary, if the button has the class `fa-pause` means that the button is currently playing, and we operate the inverse operations on it:

restore the click on his siblings,
pause the audio, 
give the button the `fa-play` class

Of course this is a simple implementation, for more advance and maybe robust one, I suggest to take a look into the MediaElement docs

```js
function getAllSiblings(el){
            let parent = el.parentElement
         let children = Array.from(parent.children)
         let siblings = children.filter(child => {
          return child !== el
          })
         return siblings
        }
    
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')
        buttons.forEach(button =>{
            let siblings = getAllSiblings(button)
            let audio = button.children[0]
            button.addEventListener('click',function(){
                if(button.classList.contains('fa-play')){
                 audio.play()
                 button.classList.remove('fa-play')
                 button.classList.add('fa-pause')
                    siblings.forEach(sibling=>{
                        sibling.style.pointerEvents = "none"
                    })
                }else{
                    audio.pause();
                    button.classList.remove('fa-pause')
                    button.classList.add('fa-play');
                    siblings.forEach(sibling =>{
                        sibling.style.pointerEvents = "auto"
                    })

                }
            })
        })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
        <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
             <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925"
                volume="1.0">
            </audio>
        </span>
         <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
            <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor"
                volume="1.0">
                 </audio>
            </span>
    </div>
```

**Dinamically switch play/pause**

```js
function getAllSiblings(el){
            let parent = el.parentElement
         let children = Array.from(parent.children)
         let siblings = children.filter(child => {
          return child !== el
          })
         return siblings
        }
        let stop = document.querySelector('.fa-stop')
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')
        stop.addEventListener('click',function(){
            buttons.forEach(button =>{
                let audio = button.firstElementChild
                if(!audio.paused){
                    audio.pause()
                    button.classList.add('fa-play')
                    button.classList.remove('fa-pause')

                }
            })
        })




        buttons.forEach(button =>{
            let audio = button.firstElementChild
            let siblings = getAllSiblings(button)
            button.addEventListener('click',function(){
                audio.play()
                button.classList.remove('fa-play')
                button.classList.add('fa-pause')
                siblings.forEach(sibling =>{
                    let siblingAudio = sibling.firstElementChild
                    sibling.addEventListener('click',function(){
                        siblingAudio.play()
                        audio.pause()
                        sibling.classList.remove('fa-play')
                        sibling.classList.add('fa-pause')
                        button.classList.remove('fa-pause')
                        button.classList.add('fa-play')
                        
                    })
                })
            })
        })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
        <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
             <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925"
                volume="1.0">
            </audio>
        </span>
         <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
            <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor"
                volume="1.0">
                 </audio>
            </span>
            
    </div>
    <span class="fa fa-stop"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. I was wondering if it would be possible to add multiple audio sources just like that in the most efficient way. So I tried to copy the HTML code you provided and paste it beneath with a different audio URL. But I'm not able to play the second button. Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/vj0tz3zm/6/

Comment: Could you tell me what needs to be fixed?

Comment: I update the solution, basically you need to iterate through the button and grab the first child, and then play or pause it

Comment: obviously you need a system to prevent other button playing when one of them is playing, maybe with pointerEvents set to None

Comment: Good answer!
Could you explain how does your code work?
Thank you!

Comment: @LimeInTheCoconut Hi, I have one last question. As opposed to what's happening, how can I pause the previous playing audio automatically when the other audio is being played? I believe the value of **pointerEvents** should be changed from "none" to something else but I'm not sure what? Thanks again.

Comment: hi, i update the answer, hope was what your looking for, no use of pointer events in this case, but you will need a button to stop all the audio currently playing

Answer (score 2):

An `<audio>` tag isn't visible if you remove the `controls` attribute or give it a `false` value. In it's place, you can design a `<button>`, link, div, etc. as the `<audio>` tag's interface. Note: this code requires no extra files to load, it is pure JavaScript and the icons are standard to every browser and system that accepts utf-8.

## Demo

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var player = document.getElementById('player');
btn.addEventListener('click', playPause, false);


function playPause(e) {

  if (player.paused || player.ended) {
    player.play();
    this.classList.add('playing');
    this.classList.remove('paused');
  } else {
    player.pause();
    this.classList.add('paused');
    this.classList.remove('playing');

  }

}
```

```css
#btn {
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px ridge grey;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none
}

#btn::before {
  content: '';
  font-size:48px;
  display:block;
  margin-top:-15px;
}

#btn.paused::before {
  content:'▶'
}

#btn.playing::before {
  content: '⏸';
  margin-left:-8.5px;
  margin-top:-18px;
}
```

```html
<audio id='player' src='http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925'></audio>
<button id='btn' class='paused'></button>
```

Comment: Your code should really use events from the media element to determine current state, rather than just assuming the state is whatever was requested when play was clicked.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events  Additionally, consider using `em` for your sizing so that things scale relatively, correctly.

Comment: The style wasn't really the point as it was the fact that the audio controls are not a problem as long as the controls attribute was either false or not there at all. As for relying on a click event, it always worked for me. I referred to [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). Thanks for the link and will refer to that one as well.

Comment: Presumably, you'll want to update the display of the button when something happens even though you didn't click the button.  Streams disconnect, have errors, or otherwise stop all the time.  You'll want to update your button when that happens, without the user having to click it.